# How to determine equality of values of JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

In the given object all values of properties are the same.

```
var obj = {
    property1: 'Some Value',
    property2: 'Some Value',
    property3: 'Some Value',
    property4: 'Some Value'
}
```

The function checkEquality should return true if all values are the same and false otherwise.

I can do the following to achieve it:

```
function checkEquality () {
    var compare = obj.propery1;

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] !== compare) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But this solution by far not the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for it.

> The `every` method executes the provided `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where `callback` returns a *falsy* value (a value that becomes `false` when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, the `every` method immediately returns `false`. Otherwise, if `callback` returned a `true` value for all elements, `every` will return `true`. `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

```js
var obj = { propery1: 'Some Value', propery2: 'Some Value', propery3: 'Some Value', propery4: 'Some Value' },
    equal = Object.keys(obj).every(function (k, i, kk) {
        return !i || obj[kk[0]] === obj[k];
    });

console.log(equal);
```

Comment: I think using `.some` to find whether any element is different would be more optimal, since it would terminate on the first difference, thus going over every element would only be a worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by @Nina, I'd just like to add something different using `reduce` and ES6 syntax:

```
const sameValues = (obj ) => {
    let keys = Object.keys( obj );
    let initial = obj[ keys[0] ];
    // val will be either the initial value or false
    let val = keys.reduce( (prev, cur) => ( obj[cur] === prev ? prev : false ), initial ); 
    return val === initial;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9tb5mdoL/

Comment: but reduce does not stop, if `false`. what if `false` is a value to test for?

Comment: 1. I know :) I have commented on your answer fully aware of this disadvantage of my approach. 2. See the linked fiddle (`false === false`)